# What's the point of a default ResourceBundleMessageSource?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to set up some message bundling. I have my 2 files:

```
message.properties
message_en_US.properties
```

Beans:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages" />
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"/>
</bean>
```

Implementation:

```
 msgSrc.getMessage(key, null, Locale.getDefault());
```

Everything works fine, but I am confused as to why alot of tutorials out there have that `message.properties` file because if I get rid of the localeResolver and set the implementation to say

```
 msgSrc.getMessage(key, null, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

It still looks at messages_en_US,  if get rid of the localResolver and still user Locale.getDefault,  it uses my computers local, which is again en_US.

I can set `message.properties` specifically, but then the Locals don't work.

So under what situation would the `message.properties` ever get used?

I feel i am missing a concept.

(and is there any way to set it up so that if Spring does not find the key in `messages_en_US.properties` it would look in `messages.properties`?)

Comment: What you describe is already the default (at least it should be). You have specified a default locale if you don't (and set `fallbackToSystemLocale` to false it will use the default (or when for the given locale there is no specific `messages.properties`). And you shouldn't be really working with the `MessageSource` yourself, the spring I18N tags should handle that for you.

Comment: I am not using this in a jsp, so I am not using the tags.

Comment: Then you should at let use a `null` locale or use the `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` instead of always specifying the same locale. If you don't want I18N then why bother having the `MessageSource` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I think if spring doesn't find the properties with the specified locale(with Locale.getDefault or get from system), then the 'message.properties' will be used. So, you can just remove `messages_en_US.properties` file, and use `messages.properties` as default for en_us and other locales.

Comment: Ok, it is NOT doing that. I moved all my keys from the en_US to the default message.properties.  When I run the app, I get - No message found under code 'user.role.remove.failure' for locale 'en_US'.]  If it does not find it, I want it to look in the default "message.properties"

Comment: Your base name is 'messages', but your file is `message.properties `, no 's'.

Answer (score 0):

> but I am confused as to why alot of tutorials out there have that `message.properties`

First of all, this is basic Java functionalatiy, provides by [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Its simple:
if you request a message property value for some locale (`en_US`), and that property does not exist in the en_US property file, `ResourceBundle` will look for the property in next more common locale (`en`), if this does not exist there, then it will look for the property in the "default" property file.

---

In your Spring example you have two steps, 
- first determine the local that is requested by the client (`localeResolver`),
- second obtain the message for the key (and locale)

So if you want that the values from `message.properties` are used, then you need to set the local stored in the users session to something that is different from `en_US`, for example: `RequestContext.changeLocale(new Locale("de")`, and then of course you need to use the spring message tag, instead of `msgSrc.getMessage(key, null, new Locale("en", "US"));` An other example is that you direcly request the property for an "not existing" languag: `msgSrc.getMessage(key, null, Locale.GERMAN);`